# How to improve the speed of the code?

Tags: arrays, swift

There is a speed problem with code below if the number of elements in arrayOfA is around 1000 and in  arrayOfB around 100 000 (run time is about several minutes). How to improve the speed ?

```
let arrayOfA = [(String, String)]() //second string in tuple is about 30 characters 
let arrayOfB = [String]() //string is about 200 characters 
var arrayOfC = [(String, Int)]()

for i in 0..<arrayOfA.count
{
     var amount = Int()
     let name = arrayOfA[i].0 + "  " + arrayOfA[i].1

     for j in 0..<arrayOfB.count
     {
         if arrayOfB[j].range(of: arrayOfA[i].1) != nil
         {
             amount += 1
         } 
     }
     if amount > 0
     {
         arrayOfC += [(name, amount)]
     }
}
```

**Update**
Meanwhile, I have made another code which is faster about 4 times. The idea is to avoid unnecessary repeating steps for function `.range(of: string)` . So, the first step is joining of reads with interval `"_"` Then, I can search to find all `Range<String.Index>` for stringA in the `stringOfarrayOfB` by using extension method `searchForStringInString` (which can find All `Range<String.Index>` of `stringIn` in `stringOut`).

```
let stringOfarrayOfB = arrayOfB.joined(separator: "_")

for i in 0..<arrayOfA.count
{
     var amount = Int()

     let arrayOfRanges = stringOfarrayOfB.searchForStringInString(stringOut: stringOfarrayOfB, stringIn: arrayOfA[i].1)

     amount = arrayOfRanges.count

     if amount > 0
     {
         let name = arrayOfA[i].0 + "  " + arrayOfA[i].1
         arrayOfC += [(name, amount)]
     }
}
```

Comment: I think your operations are not so complicated. Optimization can reduce duration but not so much. Maybe you can use thread for such an operation.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what the data is and exactly what your code is trying to achieve?

Comment: @Chris The goal is to find how many times each string from arrayA can be found in strings from arrayB, and to write it in arrayC.

Comment: you could instantly get a __much faster__ algorithm, if you create the `name` when it is necessary only (a.k.a. inside the `if`'s true-branch).

Comment: @holex Thanks for the good tip!

Comment: Can stringB match multiple stringA s? If no, you could delete them from the arrayOfB so the next time you iterate over arrayOfB there will be less Strings in it.

Comment: @Yannick Thanks!  No, stringB can match only one of the stringA. I will try.

Comment: @Yannick I have tested to remove stringB but it slower than without removing the matching string (almost 3 minutes against 2 minutes). Probably, every time after the removing of stringB a new arrayOfB is created and it takes additional time

Comment: @VYT How did you remove it? Did you look at the code I provided?

Comment: @Yannick I have used reversed oder - (0..<arrayOfB.count).reversed() and added in for loop the following - arrayOfB.remove(at: j)

Comment: Can you check if the reverse function takes up a lot of time? If yes, try making an array of the indexes and remove them after the for .. in loop. I'll update my code

Comment: @Yannick I have made a more radical change, see Update of the Question.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code after it was changed with the suggested comments.

```
let arrayOfA = [(String, String)]() //second string in tuple is about 30 characters 
let arrayOfB = [String]() //string is about 200 characters 
var arrayOfC = [(String, Int)]()

for i in 0..<arrayOfA.count
{
     var amount = Int()

     for (index, stringB) in arrayOfB.enumerate().reverse()
     {
         if stringB.range(of: arrayOfA[i].1) != nil
         {
             amount += 1
             arrayOfB.removeAtIndex(index)
         } 
     }
     if amount > 0
     {
         let name = arrayOfA[i].0 + "  " + arrayOfA[i].1
         arrayOfC += [(name, amount)]
     }
}
```

**Update**

Same functionallity without reversing the array

```
let arrayOfA = [(String, String)]() //second string in tuple is about 30 characters 
    let arrayOfB = [String]() //string is about 200 characters 
    var arrayOfC = [(String, Int)]()

for i in 0..<arrayOfA.count
{
     var amount = Int()
     var indexesToDelete = []
     for (index, stringB) in arrayOfB.enumerate()
     {
         if stringB.range(of: arrayOfA[i].1) != nil
         {
             amount += 1
             indexesToDelete.append(index)
         } 
     }

     for (index, indexToDelete) in indexesToDelete {
         arrayOfB.removeAtIndex(indexToDelete - index)
     }

     if amount > 0
     {
         let name = arrayOfA[i].0 + "  " + arrayOfA[i].1
         arrayOfC += [(name, amount)]
     }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this.

```
for i in 0..<arrayOfA.count {
        var amount = Int()
        let name = arrayOfA[i].0 + "  " + arrayOfA[i].1

        let tempArr = arrayOfB.filter { (string) -> Bool in
            string.rangeOfString(arrayOfA[i].1) != nil
        }
        amount = tempArr.count

        if amount > 0 {
            arrayOfC += [(name, amount)]
        }
    }
     arrayOfC += [(name, amount)]
 }
```

In any case filter should be more effective than for loop.

Comment: Can you prove that filter is more efficient than for loop? What should filter do different than iterate over each element in the array?

Comment: actually that concept seems about __20% slower__ than the OP's current solution; I don't understand how you did measure it more efficient... mystery.

Comment: @Yannick - filter has a complexity of O(n) in the worst case. For runs n times exactly.

Comment: @holex - how is it 20% slower? How did you calculate the 20%?

Comment: @MaxPevsner the for in loop has O(n) in every case. What's the average and best case complexity for filter? Why does filter not run n times exactly? It has to iterate over each item doesn't it?

Comment: @MaxPevsner `filter(_:)` runs n times exactly (and is therefore O(n) just like a for-loop) – see [the implementation here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift#L842).

Comment: @MaxPevsner, I simply did a performance test and measured the execution time; on a pattern of a thousand input items the OP's algorithm finishes in 0.44 secs while your finishes in 0.51 secs. that is consistent and it means your _"efficient"_ algorithm is about 20% slower. the __real question__ is on what bases can you make a statement like "_more effective_"?